# What should our logo and site design look like?

Tags: discussion

EE has always had a great following among designers, with some really beautiful sites built on top of it, **who fancies stepping up and contributing a logo/some design ideas for this site?** I can't think of a better way to gain kudos from the community (other than by answering lots of questions of course)

Related question (forked from here): [do we/Stack Exchange need to be talking to EllisLab about getting permission to use the ExpressionEngine name?](https://expressionengine.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/54/do-we-stack-exchange-need-to-be-talking-to-ellislab-about-getting-permission-to)

Comment: The fact that there has been not even so much as an official head turn from EL about this site goes to show why we need it so badly.

Comment: Now my comment is on the wrong question hah. On well.

Comment: How far can a Stackexchange Site have his own Design?

Comment: @KasparAllenbach If you look at the [Wordpress site](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/), you'll see it can be taken pretty far.

Comment: @KasparAllenbach. The [full list of SE sites](http://stackexchange.com/sites) shows a fair bit of variety in look and feel, while keeping within the same basic template. Perhaps the one which deviates from the template the most heavily is [Photography](http://photo.stackexchange.com), as its header is vertical rather than horizontal, and there's the extra photo of the week up there. The very different looks of [Arquade](http://gaming.stackexchange.com) and [TeX](http://tex.stackexchange.com) fit within the same basic template.

Answer (score 3):

Is it fair to answer this question with what it should *not* look like? :D

My vote is that it *not* be influenced at all by the current design of the EE 2.x Control Panel. Regardless of whether you like the hot pink or not ;) it's quite possible that the Control Panel will be redesigned with an upcoming release, which would leave a Stack Exchange theme based on its design looking dated.

To answer the question what it *should* look like...I know the current beta theme is pretty neutral, but it sure works great. I'd like to see it stay close to these bare essentials, emphasizing readability and usability.

Comment: Yup, spot on there Alex.

Comment: Totally agree - it's great as it is. I don't think it needs a bespoke layout/design.

Answer (score 0):

If someone comes up with a logo, I'm willing to take care of the site design.

( portfolio: http://janvl.be/ )

About the logo: does anybody know how willing Ellislab is to cooperate on this ?
We can't just use their logo, but can we use an adapted version of the EE-logo ? ( or do we have to come up with something completely different to avoid confusion about this being an official support forum or not )