# Do we/Stack Exchange need to be talking to EllisLab about getting permission to use the ExpressionEngine name?

Tags: discussion

Do we/Stack Exchange need to be talking to EllisLab about getting permission to use the ExpressionEngine name? I think I'm right that previously they have asked community sites not to directly include "ExpressionEngine" in their names, hence the proliferation of "-ee" pun-based site names.

Forked from my question [about design here](https://expressionengine.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/47/what-should-our-logo-and-site-design-look-like)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I think we should move ahead with **expressionengine.stackexchange.com**. ExpressionEngine is the name of the product about which we will answer questions. Obsfucating that under some clever wordplay would lower the find-ability and clarity of the site IMHO.

If EL were to actually mount a legal challenge the change the site name (can you even imagine it?), I think few of us will retain interest in being here anyway.

**UPDATE:** I've initiated a discussion with EL about this, and have had very prompt replies from Derek Jones. Will update folks here as their official thoughts on this shake out.

**UPDATE 2:** From Derek Jones:

> "I've been in touch with both Jay Hanlon, StackExchange's VP of community growth, as well as Michael Pryor, their  co-founder and CFO".

So it looks like EL is actively pursuing sorting out whatever they need to with the SE folks.

Comment: 100% agree with Derek.

Comment: Oh right cool, i'm very interested to hear what they think about this. Bearing in mind that if this thing actually takes off, it will most probably rank higher in search results than their own site / forums for EE questions, i'm not sure how they think that might affect their business.

Comment: I'm not sure it would affect their business at all. It's a safe assumption that anyone looking for help with EE on StackExchange is already aware of it and has bought a licence. If anything it could make *more* people aware given the profile of StackExchange.

Answer (score 3):

From the new CEO, Derek Jones and I quote:

> We haven't received any requests for licensing our marks, but I can
>   assure you that we are happy and willing to work through those issues
>   with the StackExchange folks. Whoever needs to can either contact me
>   directly or licensing at ellislab.com.

Derek can be emailed directly here: derek.jones at ellislab.com