# Name of the site?

Tags: discussion

Any ideas for a site name (not the domain name, which I think should stay as expressionengine.stackexchange.com)?

For example, the WordPress StackExchange is called [WordPress Answers](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com) and the Drupal site is called [Drupal Answers](http://drupal.stackexchange.com).

Should we follow the CMS SE trend and use **ExpressionEngine Answers**? Considering there is [some concern over using the name](https://expressionengine.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/54/do-we-stack-exchange-need-to-be-talking-to-ellislab-about-getting-permission-to) (as it's an EL trademark), I don't think naming it simply **ExpressionEngine** (as some other sites like [SalesForce](http://salesforce.stackexchange.com) and [Mathematica](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com) do) is a great idea.

**UPDATE:** I've initiated a discussion with EL about this, and have had very prompt replies from Derek Jones. Will update folks here as their official thoughts on this shake out.

**UPDATE 2:** From Derek Jones:

> "I've been in touch with both Jay Hanlon, StackExchange's VP of community growth, as well as Michael Pryor, their  co-founder and CFO".

So it looks like EL is actively pursuing sorting out whatever they need to with the SE folks.

**UPDATE 3:** Looks like the outcome of EllisLabs' discussion with the SE folks has ended in the site being called *ExpressionEngine® Answers*. Fair enough!

Comment: StackExpression, clearly!

Answer (score 18, accepted):

I don't feel strongly either way, but it could be argued that we should standardise with the other CMS' and go with ExpressionEngine Answers.

Comment: Another vote for following convention.

Comment: +1 it does what it says on the tin, as we say in Blighty

Answer (score 5):

So long as we don't attempt to pass ourselves off as any kind of official site I can't really see how Ellis Lab can object.

We should be sure to include a clear link to the "Official Support Forum" and make it clear we are not affiliated with Ellis Lab.

Comment: This notice and a link to official forums would be a great thing to add to the FAQ

Comment: Trademark dilution is Complicated, though, in the US. They could object, and there would be legal nonsense, and even though we'd almost certainly win, nobody WANTS that.

Comment: With no more official support in the forums as of their relaunch, I don't see why this is necessary.

Answer (score 5):

We'd like to avoid tacking words onto the title just for the sake of it. In both Drupal Answers and Wordpress Answers, the word "Answers" doesn't really do much to make the titles better. In hindsight, we'd rather just have "Drupal" and "Wordpress".

At the same time, we'll of course comply with legal requirements if needed. Keep us posted on the responses you get to your emails, and thanks for initiating that process!

Comment: Good to know Anna, thanks for that.

Comment: Hey Anna, I'm not a fan of tacking on words either. Also, please contact derek.jones at ellislab.com (new CEO) or licensing at ellislab.com They said they are more than happy to help in anyway they can in regards to using any of their marks.

Answer (score 3):

"The ExpressionEngine Rescue Center for lost and bewildered developers"

Answer (score 3):

StackExchange will probably need to reach out to EllisLab and come up with a solution which works for both of them. I can't think of any reason for both of them to want something other than ExpressionEngine in the title. I'd like to see the sub-domain stay as expressionengine.stackexchange.com as well. I also heard from Derek and it sounds like EL is more than willing to help in anyway they can. I will support EL's decision.

Answer (score 1):

If it gets call StackEE I'm leaving!

ExpressionEngine Answers sounds good.

Comment: bonus points for being amusing.

Comment: I was getting worried there were no "-ee" comments this far down the page. Phew.

Answer (score 0):

Name it Answeree ;) Or Exchangee :)
No. Why not just "ExpressionEngine Stack"

Come on EllisLab be cool about this.

Answer (score 0):

I like "ExpressEngine" myself. ;)

Comment: Total joke here.

Answer (score 0):

I also like "ExpressionEngine Peer Support"